# Adding image in place of text in android

Tags: android

I want to add an image (animated gif) in place of text.suppose when i enter CAT(keyword) then that CAT keyword in Edittext is replaced by image of cat...I need some guide ..
Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

Android **does'nt support .gif** files.If u want to do the second thing then add a button and on its click listener make the text view  visibilty to **GONE** and image view visibilty to **VISIBLE** giving the image path.